In an exam hall, there are three true-false questions. In how many ways can one attempt the paper if at least one question has to be attempted?
enter image description here
In an exam hall, there are three true-false questions.  In how many ways can one attempt the paper if at least one question has to be attempted?
In this we go like $3$ possibilities per question - true, false, not attempted.
So the calculation goes like $3 \times 3 \times 2 \text{(for the question mandatory)} = 18$
But the answer is $26$ because $3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27$ is total possibilities and $1$ possibility includes not attempting all questions. This makes sense, but why is my way wrong?

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

I wrote the question that was in the picture in the body of the post so it isn’t really necessary for the post

This seems more like a linguistic problem than a mathematical one. If the problem states "One of the questions is mandatory to answer", your answer is correct as the mandatory question is fixed  If is says "It is mandatory to answer at least one question", the test taker may choose any one as the "at least one". Then 26 is right.

Why doesn’t my answer work for the ‘at least ‘ question?

You are not counting the cases where the third question is left unanswered, but one of the others is not.

By creating two categories, "answered" for one particular question and  "maybe answered" for the other two, you have created a fuzzy division which is the root of the problem.
We can confirm $26$ as the correct answer by a direct count, where $A$ means answered ($2$ ways) and $N$ means not answered
$A A A: 8$
$A A N: 4$
$A N A: 4$
$N A A: 4$
$A N N: 2$
$N A N: 2$
$N N A: 2/26$
Obviously, using the complement is the  way to go, a direct count, even if abridged using binomial coefficients, as shown below, would be more tedious and error prone
$\binom31\cdot2 +\binom32\cdot4 +\binom33\cdot8 = 26$

Thanks alottttt

You're welcome ! $;;$ :)
